Periodic WorkRequest FlexInterval
As Per Developer Docs, FlexInterval is the End of Repeat Interval which is specified as last 15mins of 1 hr repeat interval. InCase My Work is scheduled for uploading chunk of data to server which is pending ie) not completed in the 15 minutes of interval..Then What is the state of Work?
        myPeriodicworkRequest = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                WorkerReminderPeriodic.class,
                60,TimeUnit.MINUTES,15,TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setInitialDelay(aInitialDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .addTag("periodic_job_notif")
                .setInputData(periodicData)
                .build();

Enqueued work is not completed within the given Flex Interval?
